# Queries regarding Digital Certificate X.509 based security?

Tags: ssl, certificate, public-key-encryption

I have been struggling with testing my application using secure HTTP using my self signed certificate and I have tons of doubts regarding the same.
I am listing down. Please help me clarify these doubts.
Considering we are implementing two way authentication in **https**, this is my current information.

```
 1. we have to create a self signed certificate for the server application. 
 2. We have to create a self signed certificate for the client application (for eg Postman)
 3. we have to create a keystore and truststore for the server application. 
 4. we have put the private key information of the server application in the keystore.
 5. We have to put the public key information of the client in the truststore.
 6. We have to save the client certificate in the postman.
```

Are all my information mentioned above correct
Given this information below is the list of doubts.

1. What should format of the public key.
2. What should format of the private key.(for eg- cms,jks,jecks,pkcs12,pkcs12s2,pkcs11direct)
3. What other steps needs to be done like any other configuration needed to be done in postman.

Other than this in general certificate and keys can be saved in different format.
Like **cms,jks,jecks,pkcs12,pkcs12s2,pkcs11direct,der,cer,crm,cert** etc.
What are these formats and what is the difference between them.

Comment: are you using openssl ? or any other mechanism to generate your keys and certificates ?

Comment: I am using iKeyMan GUI utility